# Write print functions to excel file

Tags: python

(New to python)

I want to write the print functions to my excel file that I am creating. Any idea how to do that?

I would want the below functions to show up in my table
1) Start Time
2) Saved
3) Quit
4) End Time
5) Time Elapsed
6) File Name

Below is my code I'm running.

I am running my script, then creating the excel file with a date and timestamp

```
import win32com.client
import time
import datetime
import os
import xlsxwriter

start_time = time.time()
datetime.datetime.now()
print ("--- %s Start time ---" % (datetime.datetime.now()))
datetime.datetime(2009,1,6,15,8,24,78915)

try:


    flpth = r"filepath\Test File.xlsx"
    xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(flpth )
    xlapp.displayalerts = 0
    xlapp.visible = 1
    wb.RefreshAll()
    time.sleep(5)
    wb.save
    print("---  Saved ---")
    xlapp.Quit()
    print("---  Quit ---")

    end_time = time.time()


#print the datetime / diff / file path name 
    print ("--- %s End time ---" % (datetime.datetime.now()))
    print ("--- %s Seconds ---" % round(time.time() - start_time))
    print("--- %s ---" % os.path.splitext(os.path.basename("Test File.xlsx"))[0])



# Create a workbook (with date-time) and add a worksheet.
    todays_date = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") )+ '.xlsx'
    todays_date = todays_date.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook (todays_date)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Report Summary')

# Make Columns Large Enough for Text.
    worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)
    worksheet.set_column('B:B', 20)
    worksheet.set_column('C:C', 20)
    worksheet.set_column('D:D', 20)
    worksheet.set_column('E:E', 20)
    worksheet.set_column('E:E', 20)
    worksheet.set_column('F:F', 20)

# Column Headers
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Start Time')
    worksheet.write('B1', 'File Saved')
    worksheet.write('C1', 'File Quit')
    worksheet.write('D1', 'End Time')
    worksheet.write('E1', 'Time Elapsed')
    worksheet.write('F1', 'File Name')

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
    worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
    worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)

    workbook.close()
    print ('close')



    wb = None
    xlapp = None


except:
    wb = None
    xlapp = None
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to interact with your spreadsheet with low level modules like `win32com.client`?

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand your intent with your program. I think a higher level module to interface with your spreadsheet would be good, though. There are many including `pandas`, `openpyxl`, and `xlwings` to name a few. A standard `csv` module comes with your python installation as well. Personally I prefer `xlwings` for most my spreadsheet work (you will need to `pip install xlwings`) and it can also interface with `pandas` depending on the use-case. A script that illustrates a simple use case would look like this:

```
import xlwings
import time

wb = xlwings.Book('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

start_time = time.time()
# make our headers
sheet.range("A1").value = "Start Time"
sheet.range("B1").value = "Saved"
sheet.range("C1").value = "Quit"
sheet.range("D1").value = "End Time"
sheet.range("E1").value = "Time Elapsed"
sheet.range("F1").value = "File Name"

row = 2
while True:
    sheet.range("A{}".format(row)).value = start_time
    sheet.range("B{}".format(row)).value = "No"
    sheet.range("C{}".format(row)).value = "No"
    now = time.time()
    sheet.range("D{}".format(row)).value = now
    sheet.range("E{}".format(row)).value = now - start_time
    sheet.range("F{}".format(row)).value = "Some name"
    row += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Where a sample of the output after a few seconds looks like:

[image: output worksheet]

I think you would need to be more specific in your question as to what you are trying to do if you wanted to get more appropriate solutions.